# make input text same height as bootstrap selectpicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make the `input type text` the same size as bootstrap's selectpicker, right now, the input is shorter than the select.

I've tried `$("#selectpicker_picker").height()` but it gives me a much bigger height.

https://jsfiddle.net/zf9cv6jg/

Edit: I can kinda force it by just adding padding, but I was wondering if there was a more accurate way.

Comment: please show some code and provide A FIDDLE

Comment: didn't you use the grid system or you don't want ??

Comment: @AsifuzzamanRedoy Not sure what you mean by the grid system.

Comment: bootstrap grid/column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello see the below fiddle .As you are using bootstrap it would be better if you use form control

```
 <form class="form-inline">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label>Name</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label>Date:</label>
 <select class='selectpicker'>
 <option value="something">something</option>
 </select>
 </div>    
 </form>
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/zf9cv6jg/1/)

Comment: I think that should be good, didn't realise there were form css

Comment: What if user will use `input-sm` for input? Select box will be bigger!This answer is correct only for default size.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add form-control class to your input text field to give it same height as selectpicker like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"/>
```

and for the width you can use col-xx-xx classes such as col-xs-6